# Cannot get a 'bad response' from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax to tell me whether my server is up or not.  I've made a simple page with just one Ajax call.  When the server is up, it comes back with the xmlhttp.responseText.  IF the server is down it is supposed to say "SERVER DOWN"...but when I load the page, then turn off Apache, it still says that the server is up.  Is there some other way I should be doing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var xmlhttp;
var url = "http://192.168.0.5/ajax_info.txt";
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction()
{
loadXMLDoc(url,function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  else
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "Server Down!";
    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page is probably cached, use a cache buster in the url. e.g.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",url+'?_dc='+(new Date()).getTime(),true);
```

Comment: yup that was it.  Thanks for the hint!