# google maps xml markers

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

I have the following code stored in a 'genxml.php' that generates markers on google maps. The file is called from another file 'mobileInterface.php'. If I add another marker location in the database everything is working fine on a computer browser, the only problem that I have is when loading from a mobile browser, markers do no update instantly, I have to exit the browser and load it again to update. Else I have to load the 'genxml.php' directly from the URL, sort of downloading the contents and then load 'mobileInterface.php' again.

I have tried not caching the page contents but still I have this problem. Any ideas please?

//genxml.php

```
$query = "SELECT * ,DATE_FORMAT( ts,  '%d-%m-%Y  :  %H.%i.%s' ) as tz FROM dataentry WHERE caseStatus = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");


// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
    echo '<marker ';
    echo 'id="' . parseToXML($row['id']) . '" ';
    echo 'riskCategory="' . parseToXML($row['riskCategory']) . '" ';
    echo 'EventAccidentSubject="' . parseToXML($row['EventAccidentSubject']) . '" ';
    echo 'description="' . parseToXML($row['description']) . '" ';
    echo 'peopleInvolved="' . parseToXML($row['peopleInvolved']) . '" ';
    echo 'hazards="' . parseToXML($row['hazards']) . '" ';
    echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
    echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
    echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';  
    echo 'caseStatus="' . parseToXML($row['caseStatus']) . '" ';
    echo 'ts="' . $row['tz'] . '" ';   
    echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

//mobileInterface.php

```
var mobileInterfaceServer = "http://10.0.0.21/genxml.php";          
downloadUrl(mobileInterfaceServer, function(markers) {//replace markers with data
            var xml = markers.responseXML;//replace markers with data
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            selectBox = document.getElementById('destination');
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var riskCategory = markers[i].getAttribute("riskCategory");
                var EventAccidentSubject = markers[i].getAttribute("EventAccidentSubject");          
                var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));                    

                html = "<b>" + EventAccidentSubject + "</b> <br/>" + address;

                displayLocation(markers[i]);
                //displayLocation(point);
                addOption(selectBox, markers[i].getAttribute("EventAccidentSubject"), point);

                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html); 

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a timestamp to the request for data from the server as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456737/cannot-get-a-bad-response-from-ajax-call/15456754#15456754)